# Gutenberg LinkControl suggestionsQuery not working

Tags: block-editor

I have a link control like so:

```
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";
import {
  __experimentalLinkControl as LinkControl,
} from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import "./editor.scss";

export default function ({ attributes, setAttributes }) {

  return (
          <LinkControl
            suggestionQuery={{
              type: "post",
              subtype: "page",
            }}
          />
  );
}
```

However, typing into the search input shows all post types (I want it to just show pages). [The documentation says](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-editor/src/components/link-control#suggestionsquery) to use it as so:

> ### suggestionsQuery
>
> `Type: Object`
> `Required: No`
> Controls the query
> parameters used to search for suggestions. For example, to limit a
> query to just Page types use:

```
<LinkControl
    suggestionQuery={ {
        type: 'post',
        subtype: 'page',
    } }
/>
```

I think I've followed that pretty nicely.

The only question in my mind is, the docs also state:

> ### Data sources
>
> By default LinkControl utilizes the `__experimentalFetchLinkSuggestions` API from `core/block-editor` in order to retrieve search suggestions for matching post-type entities.
>
> By default this **provides no functionality** and so you must implement and provide this in your own Editor instance ([example](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/65c752816f46a9334b84f4801d80dea00ed76fba/packages/editor/src/components/provider/use-block-editor-settings.js#L114-L115)).

The example:
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/65c752816f46a9334b84f4801d80dea00ed76fba/packages/editor/src/components/provider/use-block-editor-settings.js#L114-L115

I cannot wrap my head around. It also may not be why my code isn't working. Would anyone be able to show how I can make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, typing into the search input shows all post types (I want it
> to just show pages).

That's most likely because your code, as well as the *example* in the [documentation](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-editor/src/components/link-control#suggestionsquery), used the wrong property name — `suggestionQuery` — which should actually be `suggestionsQuery` (note the plural "suggestions").

So try using `suggestionsQuery`?

```js
<LinkControl
    suggestionsQuery={ {
        type: 'post',
        subtype: 'page',
    } }
/>
```